# Can a single app engine back end be used for a java and android front end?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cloud

I have just learned that we can use Google app engine to create back end for an android app. Similarly we can create backend for java application using google app engine. Can we create a single back end which will cater  to both Java front end and a android application.

Comment: Can you give me some more info.Is there a good tutorial which I can refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use RESTful API, for example, you can have any number of different clients talk to the same backend.

Comment: Could give me some more details on that. If I create a restful web service and host it on google app engine, and at client end I will need to write separate code for android and java? Is my understanding correct? The client side will be still heavy right because, I need to have most functionalities duplicated for java n android.

Comment: If you want to reuse code between clients running in different environments, you can package common functionality into a separate jar available to both clients.

Comment: I was able to achieve this, by using Spring MVC restful services. but i did not use app engine just plain web services. I used AngularJS for web client and an android application. Much of the functionality is in services layer. thank you for the answers. also posting a link to github https://github.com/lakmez/NeedARide